# javascript functions are not called

Tags: javascript

in a JSP page I want to call a javascript function. But when I call it inside a "a" tag it isn't hit.
But when I put an "onload" parameter in the "body" tag as follows,
onload="" the function I called inside < a > tag is hit.
Can anybody explain this situation please.

Comment: please post your code...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:mufunction('hello-world')">Click Me</a>
```

If you are using the similar code above, then it should be working. Please debug your code via the developer consoles built-in a browser.

Please check the [this](http://jsbin.com/epoxoy/2/edit) link and check whether it is same as yours.

Comment: This definition of Anchor is invalid. HREF must not have javascript code. More valid definition is: _<a href="#" onclick="javascript:mufunction('hello-world');return false;">Click Me</a>_ for an example.